# Grails 2.2.4/Spock: Stubbed Service Interaction: Why is a rejected value being ignored?

Tags: mocking, spock, stubbing, grails-2.2

Given a simple domain with an injected service, which is used to perform a certain validation inside a constraint, like:

```
package org.example.domain

class Ninja {

    String name
    String sensei
    String village

    def ninjaService

    static transients = ['ninjaService']

    static constraints = {
        ....
        village nullable:true, validator:{ val, obj, errors ->
            obj.ninjaService.validate(obj)
        }
    }
}
```

And a simple Spec, which stubs the service behavior, such:

```
package org.example.domain

import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import spock.lang.Specification
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

import org.example.services.NinjaService

@TestFor(Ninja)
class NinjaSpec extends Specification {

    def 'Should succeed at validating the village using a stubbed method'() {
        given:
            def instance = new Ninja(village: 'Leaf')
            instance.ninjaService = Mock(NinjaService)
        when:
            instance.validate(['village'])
        then:
            1 * instance.ninjaService.validate(instance) >> { final Ninja ninja ->
                ninja.errors.rejectValue 'village', 'should.be.an.error', [].toArray(), null
                ninja.log.debug "[NINJA SERVICE MOCK] (VALIDATING) 'village' FIRED! ninja.errors['village']?.code: '${ninja.errors['village']?.code}'"
            }
        and:
            instance.errors['village']?.code == 'should.be.an.error'
    }
}
```

Then, what happens is that the instance.errors['village']?.code is null.
Check it out:

```
grails test-app unit:spock -clean -echoOut NinjaSpec

| Compiling 121 source files

| Running 1 spock test... 1 of 1

--Output from Should succeed at validating the village via mock--

2016-02-04 19:51:00.219 [main] grails.app.domain.org.example.domain.Ninja
 DEBUG [NINJA SERVICE MOCK] (VALIDATING) 'village' FIRED! ninja.errors['village']?.code: 'should.be.an.error'

| Failure:  Should succeed at validating the village via mock(org.example.domain.NinjaSpec)
|  Condition not satisfied:

instance.errors['village']?.code == 'should.be.an.error'
|        |     |            |    |
|        |     null         null false
|        org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors
org.example.domain.Ninja : (unsaved)

    at org.example.domain.NinjaSpec.Should succeed at validating the village via mock(NinjaSpec.groovy:36)

| Completed 1 Spock test, 1 failed in 2032ms
```

Why doesn't the instance hold the code **should.be.an.error** that had been set inside the stub interaction?

[Sample project @ github](https://github.com/roalcantara/grails-transient-property-validator-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems you are not using the service but a mock, so it might not be validating anything. Try to create an instance of the service instead of mocking it.

Comment: So, actually, what I'd like to do is to "mock" the service behavior in this test. For this test purpose, I'd like to ignore the service implementation and simulate its behaviour, setting the error manually. The curious thing is that I've tried to do this even using **instance.ninjaService.metaclass.validate = {}** in the **given** block and it does not work either. Why would that be?

Comment: try the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363401/unable-to-mock-grails-service-method-when-unit-testing-controller-missingmetho mocking service methods with closures, so you can add your own logic, like adding errors to the Ninja instance.

Comment: Thanks @pablo-pazos, but I've got the same result using mockFor()/createMock(). Although the closure/stub is being called before the when block, it seems as if what happens inside the closure/stub is simply ignored. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here..

Answer (score 0):

This implementation suggested by @PabloPazos using mockFor() and createMock() works like a charm!

```
def 'Should succeed at validating the village via mock'() {
    given:
        def instance = new Ninja(village: 'Leaf')
        def ninjaServiceMock = mockFor(NinjaService)
        ninjaServiceMock.demand.validate { final Ninja ninja ->
            ninja.errors.rejectValue 'village', 'should.be.an.error', [].toArray(), null
        }
        instance.ninjaService = ninjaServiceMock.createMock()
    when:
        instance.validate(['village'])
    then:
        instance.errors['village']?.code == 'should.be.an.error'
}
```

I still don't understand, though, why the Spock stubbed service didn't work.

Comment: That test is jusr rejecting a value explicitly.

Comment: Exactly. As I've said, I don't really like this approach. But it was, unfortunately, the only one that worked.

Comment: I understand, but the test is not testing much. Please share the code you tried and didn't worked to take a look.

Comment: Hi @PabloPazos! I was testing the code that I'd written implementing your suggestion to posted it here and.. it worked out! I might have done something wrong in my first attempt. Thus, I'm going to update this answer giving you the credits and accept your answer, ok? Thanks a bunch!